# pattern searching of binary data

Tags: c, antivirus

I am trying to build antivirus in C.
I do that like this:

1. Read data of virus and picture file to scanned.
2. Check if virus data appear in picture data.

I read the data of scanned file and virus file like this: ( I read the file by binary mode because the file is picture(.png) )

```
// open file
file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
if (!file)
{
    printf("Error: can't open file.\n");
    return 0;
}

// Allocate memory for fileData
char* fileData = calloc(fileLength + 1, sizeof(char));

// Read data of file.
fread(fileData, fileLength, 1, file);
```

after i read the file data and the Virus data i check if the virus appear in the file like this:

```
char* ret = strstr(fileData, virusID);
if (ret != NULL)
    printf("Infetecd file");
```

It does not work even though in my picture i have VirusID.
I want to check if the binary data of virus appear in binary data of picture.

For example: my binary data of my virus http://pastebin.com/xZbWA9qu

And the binary data of my picture(with the virus): http://pastebin.com/yjXr84kr

Comment: what is `fileLength `?

Comment: What if file is binary?

Comment: @SouravGhosh its variable, i check with step by step the number of length is correct.

Comment: @stark i read the file by binary mode because the file is picture (.png)

Comment: You know that binary data can contain embedded zeroes? And you know that in C the string terminator character is a zero? Then how do you think you can use a function like `strstr`, or any other string function which looks for string terminator characters?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you for your comment, you can give me option to check if the picture have the virus? ( How to read the data) ( how to check if the file infected)

Answer (score 2):

First, note the order of arguments of `fread`, `fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` so to get the number of bytes, it's better to do `fread(fileData, 1, fileLength, file);`. Your code will return 0 or 1 depends on whether there is enough data to be read in the file, not the number of bytes it has read.

Second, `strstr` is to search for strings, not memory blocks, in order to search binary blocks, you need to write your own, or you can use the GNU extension function `memmem`.

```
// Allocate memory for fileData
char *fileData = malloc(fileLength);

// Read data of file.
size_t nread = fread(fileData, 1, fileLength, file);

void *ret = memmem(fileData, nread, virusID, virusLen);
if (ret != NULL)
    printf("Infetecd file");
```

Comment: You think its work to check if the  binary data of virus appear in the binary data of picture?

Comment: @YairB. Can you rephrase your question? I thought that was what you want to do.

Comment: I build a antivirus that check pictures file by binary data.
I have  a binary data of virus and I want to check if the binary data of the virus appear in the binary data of the picture.

Comment: @YairB. Yes, that's why I suggested use `memmem` it searches the binary data for the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the first byte of the virus signature, if you find it then see if the next byte is the second byte of the signature, and so on until you have checked and matched all bytes of the signature. Then the file is infected. If not all bytes matches then search again for the first byte of the signature.